how can you tell whether $\chi'-\chi$ is a character

If $\chi$ is an irreducible character and $\chi'$ is any character, how can you tell whether $\chi'-\chi$ is a character without constructing the corresponding representations?

In order to verify that a function is a character, we just need to show that it's the trace of a representation. I found the following seemingly related post, but I'm not sure how to solve this problem using the theorem that if a class function $\chi$ is a character iff for every irreducible character $\chi_i,\langle \chi, \chi_i\rangle$ is an integer.

We have $\chi'-\chi$ a character if and only if $\langle \chi',\chi\rangle\neq 0$.
Proof:
Let $V$ be the representation whose character is $\chi'$ and $U$ the irreducible representation with character $\chi$.  If $\chi'-\chi$ is the character of a representation $W$, then $W\oplus U\cong V$, as they have the same character.  Thus $U$ is a summand of $V$ and occurs in $V$ with multiplicity $\langle \chi',\chi\rangle> 0$.
Conversely, if $\langle \chi',\chi\rangle\neq 0$, then $U$ is a summand of $V$ and has complement $W$ with character $\chi'-\chi$.
This assumes we are working with a finite group over $\mathbb{C}$.

isn't the right condition $\langle \chi',\chi\rangle>0$, rather than $\neq 0$ ?

@GreginGre As it will be a non-negative integer, they are equivalent.
